# make http post/put request using angular via MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am calling Put Method using angular 4 as below.I call Home controller from angular. It is working fine for GET Method but I can't pass body parameter from Post/Put Method. This is my angular code

```
public saveData(item: CustomerList[]): any {             
    let header = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header });
    return this
        .http
        .post('/Home/Put?endpoint=myApi/CustomerService/', JSON.stringify(item), options)
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
            const response = res.text();
        })
```

It hits to controller method below. But Data parameter set as null.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    [HttpPut]
    public object Put(string endpoint, [FromBody ]object data)
    {
      // ** My issue is here data is getting as null **
        var result = _myRestSharp.Put<object,object>(endpoint, data);
        return result;
    }
    [HttpGet]//Working fine
    public object Get(string endpoint)
    {
        var result = _reveraApiClient.Get<object>(endpoint, null, 
        return result;
    }
}
```

any suggestion why is the variable 'data' is getting as null ??

Comment: you are using `POST` instead of `PUT` in your angular?

Comment: Also route template does not match URL being called from client.

Comment: no same issue I have with Post also. for the moment I am working with put method

Comment: @Chanu 
The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FromBody] parameter called 'data' is of type object. MVC cannot deserialize your posted Json into an object type because it doesn't have matching properties.
Either create a class in c# that the data can be serialized into, or use type JObject. A class is recommended because it's clear what data your method is expecting.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. Finally I was able to solve that change my Controller to API Controller